# concating checkboxes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field called `delivery_day` which is of type `string` in `delivery_preference` model.

In form, I want to provide **7 checkboxes** for each day like Sunday,Monday,etc., and later want to concat.

For example if a user checks Sunday and Friday, I want to concat & store it as `"Sunday,Friday"` in `delivery_day` field.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: please post your form with questions as well

Comment: I'm still working on it. Basically It will look like <%= form_for(@delivery_preference) do |f| %> <% end %>.                                                In between I want to provide 7 checkboxes and later concat and save it in delivery_day field. Thanks!!

Comment: I have posted an answer below which specifies how you can design your form and how to save your desired result in `delivery_day` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design your form like this -

```
<%= form_for @delivery_preference do |f|%>
 <%= f.check_box :delivery_day, {multiple: true}, "Sunday" %>Sunday
 <%= f.check_box :delivery_day, {multiple: true}, "Monday" %> Monday
 <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

After submitting the form, you can get your check box selections in your controller as follows:

```
def your_action_name
  params[:delivery_preference][:delivery_day].delete("0")
  DeliveryPreference.create(delivery_day: params[:delivery_preference][:delivery_day].join(","))
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Might have better solutions, but when I encountered similar problem, I used `check_box_tag` to solve it.

```
<%= check_box_tag "delivery_preference[delivery_day][0]", 'monday' %>Monday
<%= check_box_tag "delivery_preference[delivery_day][1]", 'tuesday' %>Tuesday
<%= check_box_tag "delivery_preference[delivery_day][2]", 'wednesday' %>Wednesday
<%= check_box_tag "delivery_preference[delivery_day][3]", 'thursday' %>Thursday
<%= check_box_tag "delivery_preference[delivery_day][4]", 'friday' %>Friday
<%= check_box_tag "delivery_preference[delivery_day][5]", 'saturday' %>Saturday
<%= check_box_tag "delivery_preference[delivery_day][6]", 'sunday' %>Sunday
```

then you will receive an array like { deliver_day: ['monday', 'tuesday'] } in you controller. You can choose to concat in your controller, and then save, or you can move the logic to your model.

in your controller, you strong parameter should be like

```
params.require(:delivery_preference).permit(.., :deliver_day => [])
```

to permit the array.

Comment: Don't need to specify indexes in arrays like this. Can be just `check_box_tag "delivery_preference[delivery_day][]"` for all checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to leave a brief comment yet.  However, does your migration have `delivery_day` have something similar to `t.boolean :public, default: true_or_false_here` within it?

If so, within the `form`, you could have something like:

```
...
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :public, class: 'checkbox' do %>
          <%= f.check_box :public %> Monday
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :public, class: 'checkbox' do %>
          <%= f.check_box :public %> Tuesday
        <% end %>
      </div>
...
```

After above, you could designate (via boolean logic) your "concat & store it as "`Sunday,Friday`"